# Reading in string of nested JSON lists and dictionaries with Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am having trouble reading data in python. A sample of one of the rows is:

```
foo_brackets='{"KEY2":[{"KEY2a":[{"KEY2a1":"4","KEY2a2":"5"},{"KEY2a1":"6","KEY2a2":"7"}],"KEY2b":"8"}],"KEY3":"9"}'
```

When I load with `json`, the value for `KEY2` is read in as a list, because of the brackets, which then prevents me from getting at my desired result, which is the value of `KEY2b`:

```
>>> import json
>>> foo_brackets_json=json.loads(foo_brackets)
>>> foo_brackets_json['KEY2']['KEY2b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I could just try to remove the brackets, but there actually is a value that should be a list, `KEY2a`. You can see this if I strip out all the brackets and try to convert to JSON:

```
>>> foo_no_brackets='{"KEY2":{"KEY2a":{"KEY2a1":"4","KEY2a2":"5"},{"KEY2a1":"6","KEY2a2":"7"},"KEY2b":"8"},"KEY3":"9"}'
>>> json.loads(foo_no_brackets)
# Traceback omitted since it's just the python error
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 45 (char 45)
```

`foo_brackets` does appear to be valid JSON (I tested [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), with the quotes removed) and got the following:

```
{
   "KEY2":[
      {
         "KEY2a":[
            {
               "KEY2a1":"4",
               "KEY2a2":"5"
            },
            {
               "KEY2a1":"6",
               "KEY2a2":"7"
            }
         ],
         "KEY2b":"8"
      }
   ],
   "KEY3":"9"
}
```

## Question:

Is there a way for me to read objects like `foo_brackets` so that I can call `foo_brackets_json['KEY2']['KEY2b']`?

Comment: What's wrong with using `foo_brackets_json['KEY2'][0]['KEY2b']`?

Comment: Why do you think those brackets are 'extra'? They are valid JSON, as you discovered, and they denote a *list*. They are not 'extra' other than you appear to not expect there to be anything but 1 such nested dictionary.

Comment: You're both right - thanks for the quick feedback. It was just a different format than I was used to seeing and got thrown off by the combination of lists and dictionaries.

Comment: It's annoying that the value associated with `'KEY2'` wraps the dictionary in a list. But that's pretty tame compared to some of the truly horrible things that some people do with JSON. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo_brackets_json['KEY2']` references a *list*, here with one element.

You'll have to use integer indices to reference the dictionaries contained in that list:

```
foo_brackets_json['KEY2'][0]['KEY2b']
```

Don't try to remove the brackets; there could be 0 or more nested dictionaries here. You'll have to determine what should happen in those cases where you don't have just 1 nested dictionary.

The above hardcoded reference assumes there is always at least one such a dictionary in the list, and doesn't care if there are more than one.

You could use *looping* to handle the 0 or more case:

```
for nested in foo_brackets_json['KEY2']:
    print(nested['KEY2b'])
```

Now you are handling each nested dictionary, one by one. This'll work for the empty list case, and if there is more than one.

You could make having 0 or more than one an error:

```
if len(foo_brackets_json['KEY2']) != 1:
    raise ValueError('Unexpected number of results')
```

etc. etc. It all depends on your actual use-case.